# Julia function return wrong value than expected

Tags: arrays, function, julia

I am trying to create a function in Julia to initialize an array. Here is my code:

```
function create_A(i)
   A = zeros(4,1)
   A[i,1] = 1.0
   return A
end
create_A(3)
```

I was expecting to get `[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]`, but instead, I get 6. I am totally confused. Can anyone explain why?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that if you intend to create a one-dimensional array, you should write `zeros(4)` instead of `zeros(4,1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined another more specific method for `create_A` in your Julia session. You can look at all methods with `methods(create_A)`

Comment: Thank you @Oscar! You are right. I realized I did have two "create_A" methods defined. Wow, this one is hard to find. I didn't know Julia allows two functions with the same name in the workspace.  I used Ctrl+D to clear the workspace, then run it again, and now it works.